# Displaying integers in a wxpython listctrl

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I have a wxPython ListCtrl with five columns. Four of these hold strings, the last one has integer values. I have been storing these as strings (i.e. '4', '17', etc.). However, now that I have added a ColumnSorterMixin to let me sort specific columns in the list, I'm finding, of course, that the integer column is being sorted lexically rather than numerically.

Is there a simple way of fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the most robust way of doing custom sort is to use [SortItems()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrlsortitems) function in wx.ListCtrl. Note that you have to provide item data for each item (using `SetItemData()`)

Just provide your own callback, say:

```
def sortColumn(item1, item2):
    try: 
        i1 = int(item1)
        i2 = int(item2)
    except ValueError:
        return cmp(item1, item2)
    else:
        return cmp(i1, i2)
```

Didn't check it, but something along these lines should work for all columns, unless you have a column where some values are strings representing integers and some are not.